# Is it true that $ \left[ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left((x - a)^{n+1} (x - b)^{n+1}\right) \right]_{x=a} = 0 $ for positive integer $ n $?

Tags: derivatives

While solving another problem I stumbled upon this fact that seems to be true but I do not how to prove.

For a positive integer $ n $, we have
$$
\left[ \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left((x - a)^{n+1} (x - b)^{n+1}\right) \right]_{x=a} = 0.
$$

Is this true? If so, how can I prove this? I tried proving it by induction but I failed to reduce the case of ( n + 1 ) to that of ( n ) in a way that would make the induction work. A proof of this statement (if it is true) would be very appreciated by me.

A proof that does not rely on induction is fine too.

Comment: Use the product formula and induction but first replace $n+1$ by $m>n$ and formulate the statement of induction correctly.

Comment: Think of it this way. With each derivative you take, you get an extra term involving a lower power of $x-a$. But even after $n$ derivatives, the final extra term you get will still have a factor of $(x-a)^{n+1-n}=x-a$. So at the end, you have a sum in which every term has a factor of $x-a$.

Comment: It might be easier to prove by induction that for any polynomial $P(x)$, $\left[\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (x-a)^{n+1}P(x)\right]_{x=a}=0$